# iOS: Is it possible to launch a call from background in in-house app without jailbreaking the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-privateapi, core-telephony

I need to make autorecall functionality in my enterprise app.
It must do:
**1. catch incoming call**
**2. make a recall after call was finished**

First point is done. I was able to catch incoming call using private APIs.
But I can't make a recall, because my app is in background after the call.

Can anyone tell me how to:
**1. Make a call while app is in background.**
I didn't found any private APIs for calling from background. So I don't know if this is even possible to make a call from background even using private APIs.

**2. Bring my app to foreground (this way I will be able to make a call using public API).**
Everything that I found for now is not working without jailbreak (without entitlements in provisioning). Maybe someone managed to bring app to foreground programmatically without need of "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications" or "com.apple.frontboard.launchapplications" entitlements? Or maybe someone managed to add those entitlements into enterprise provisioning?

**Important notes:**
- I need this for enterprise purposes, I'm not planning to submit this app to App Store, so I don't care that Apple will refuse the app.
- Ways that require jailbreak will not work for me.

Comment: hey, did you ever find a answer to this?  I am in the same boat as you.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, since iOS 8.3 even catching the incoming call is not possible anymore. Those private APIs that I've used do not work any more :(